# Font not getting applied in a web site viewed in IPad

Tags: html, css

We are using the following CSS for applying font style for our website.. However the style is not getting applied when the website is viewed through an iPad device. Please help me solve this issue.

```
@font-face {font-family: boldFont;src: url( 'whitney-bold.ttf' );}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using CSS @font-face with the iPad/iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058342/using-css-font-face-with-the-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 3):

You need SVG format font files to work across the iOS devices. Try using the following link to generate all the required formats for cross browser compatibility using `@font-face`.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Upload the font you require, and it will generate a package with the following font formats:

**TrueType Fonts**  - Firefox 3.5+ , Opera 10+, Safari 3.1+, Chrome 4.0.249.4+
**EOT fonts** - Internet Explorer 4+
**WOFF fonts** - Firefox 3.6+, Internet Explorer 9+, Chrome 5+
**SVG fonts** - iPad and iPhone

Comment: We tried out the solution.. Still its not working... How ever its showing a default font not the original "whitney" font

Comment: Well.. we figured it out on our end itself.. the corresponding font ".otf" file fixed the problem.. thought of sharing it others.. (BTW svg didn't worked for us)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before, it seems. [Using CSS @font-face with the iPad/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058342/using-css-font-face-with-the-ipad-iphone)

Both this other question and various blog searches suggest that ios mobile safari requires you to convert certain font types to svg for them to render properly.