# @font-face not working with Safari in Mac OS or in Ipad

Tags: css

I am having a problem with @font-face. I am using a custom font named Whitney. It is working properly with all browsers in Windows(including Safari). But **not working with Safari in Mac OS or in Ipad**. From internet, I have got the idea that .svg font format will work fine with safari. So I tried that as well. But still it is not getting applied. Even the .ttf font files of other fonts were working perfectly in Safari. Anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code...its given below. Or is the problem with this font?

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: bookFont;
    src: url("../fonts/whitney-book.eot");
    src: url( '../fonts/whitney-book.ttf' )format("truetype"), url('../fonts/whitneybook.svg#Whitney-book') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Does the #Whitney-book match the id in your SVG file? Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058342/using-css-font-face-with-the-ipad-iphone

Comment: Yes. the id #Whitney-book is correct. It is the same id that I have found inside the SVG file. "<font id="Whitney-book" horiz-adv-x="523" >
"

Comment: Are you sure the relative-urls are pointing to the right directory? Try removing the ../. That or putting the fonts directly in the same folder as the css.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks incorrect. You have a semi-colon when you need a comma, and you need a space between ')' and 'format'.

Last, make sure those urls resolve properly in a regular browser. They need to be relative to the CSS file, and not the webroot.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: bookFont;
    src: url('../fonts/whitney-book.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url( '../fonts/whitney-book.ttf' ) format('truetype'), url('../fonts/whitneybook.svg#Whitney-book') format('svg'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use it like this :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
```

}