# @font-face is not working in server (.net application)

Tags: .net, css, font-face

@font-face is not working from the server url when i browse in safari 5.1+

When I am browsing html file, it is looking excellent in safari. But, when I converted into aspx (.net) file, it is not looking good at all.

Comment: Can you please add the code for the html file you have a problem with?

Comment: Also, is it different for different browsers or have you only tested in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

please post the css your're using.

an issue might be you don't have the mime type defined in your IIS configuration
http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/IIS/newmime

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though.

Try this. May be you are missing this.

[@font-face not working with Safari in Mac OS or in Ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389644/font-face-not-working-with-safari-in-mac-os-or-in-ipad)